# Android app for viewing C# and VB files

Tags: android

I'm a developer and I wanted an app just to review code on my Android.

So this are the ideal keypoints, it doesn't need to have all of them:

- tree based directory for easy file selection
- code highlighting in VB, C# (other languages appreciated)
- text line break so it would scroll only vertically and not horizontally (required)
- customizable font size
- little symbol at the line break to distinguish from a normal line
- code to function jump, go to definition

Well, if this is asking too much is there any text viewer app with tree directory and line break?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i use. Not all your desired features but close: [920 text editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jecelyin.editor)

Stated by the product page (and while i have not tested all, everything i needed from it works flawlessly)

> 920 Text Editor is a run on the Android phone a powerful text editor,
>   anywhere, you can easily view or edit your code, you can also use it
>   as e-book reader to open txt novel, it is like on Windows EmEditor,
>   EditPlus so powerful.
>
> Features:
>
> 1. Multi Tab, you can open different files in different tabs to facilitate you in a different text of this switch to edit
> 2. syntax highlighting: ASP, ActionScript, C/C++, C#, Erlang, Frink, HTML/XML/WML, CSS, Javascript, Java, JSP, Perl, PHP, Python,
>      Shell/Bash, Lua, SQL, VB/VBS, Tcl, TeX/LaTeX, Verilog, AutoHotKey,
>      AutoLisp, PowerShell, Pascal,Fortran, ColdFusion, VHDL
> 3. show line numbers
> 4. show blank characters (tabs, line breaks)
> 5. automatically detects the open file encoding, and you can also convert the current file encoding support: ISO-2022-CN, BIG5, EUC-TW,
>      GBK, GB2312, ISO-8859-5, KOI8-R, WINDOWS-1251, MACCYRILLIC, IBM866,
>      IBM855, ISO-8859-7, WINDOWS-1253, ISO-8859-8, WINDOWS-1255,
>      ISO-2022-JP, SHIFT_JIS, EUC-JP, ISO-2022-KR, EUC-KR, UTF-8, UTF-16BE /
>      UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE / UTF-32LE / X-ISO-10646-UCS-4-34121 /
>      X-ISO-10646-UCS-4-21431, WINDOWS-1252
> 6. easy toolbar, you can quickly make a new file, open, save, save as, undo/redo, and some commonly used symbols, back to last edit location,
>      etc.
> 7. list of recently opened files history
> 8. regular search, replace or replace all
> 9. change the font and font size
> 10. "Word wrap" switch
> 11. lock the screen orientation in: auto, horizontal or vertical
> 12. remember the last open file
> 13. hide the soft keyboard, long press the edit area can be turn on
> 14. long press the "edit area" you can convert selected text to uppercase or lowercase
> 15. auto indent
> 16. keep the screen in the awake state
> 17. you can run at ROOT permissions
> 18. easy's file manager, you can delete or rename the file, or open with other application to view, copy/move etc. to manage files
> 19. use the volume keys to quickly switch the display/hide the toolbar, full-screen mode
> 20. preview the HTML file
> 21. power Color Picker
> 22. use Grep recursive search keyword in the path
> 23. you can use the "Preferences" menu "Donate" page to the donate it

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NickWilde, you are right, my fault. I didn't have very clear the rules in SoftwareRecomendations. Included the information from the developer. Thank you

Comment: It is a good app. Many options and languages.